# FFmpeg - Overlay one video onto another video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, openframeworks

> I understand that this is a very open ended question. I have done some initial reading into [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org), but now require some guidance.

#### Problem

- I have a video `input.mov`.
- I would like to overlay another video on top of `overlay.wov`.
- The result should be a single video (`output.mov`).

#### Notes

- Done some initial reading into [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) and read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698372/ffmpeg-overlay-video-on-top-of-another-video).

Thanks - C.

#### Edits

1. Backend is Go/Ruby. Open to using a new language.
2. The audio from the first video should be kept.
3. Setting the interval at which the overlay starts would be great.

#### Current Solution

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -i overlay.mov -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]overlay[out]" -shortest -map [out] -map 0:1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 18  output.mov
```

This nearly works, however:

- Overlay is cut short even though the two videos (`input.mov` & `overlay.mov`) are the same length.
- I cannot start the overlay at any interval apart from `0:00`.

Comment: what backend technology you are using? PHP, .NET, struts, python!!?

Comment: @Tarunn - added answer to post.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard thanks for the comment, have added quite a lot more detail and included my current solution. I believe it is different due to the audio and interval requirements.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you just want a ffmpeg command, try

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -i overlay.mov \
-filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS-10/TB[a]; \
                 [0:v][a]overlay=enable=gte(t\,5):shortest=1[out]" \
-map [out] -map 0:a \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a copy \
output.mov
```

This starts the overlay at 5 seconds with the overlaid video start point being `00:15`.

`setpts=PTS-10/TB` is `setpts=PTS+(overlay_delay-video_trim_in)/TB`

`overlay=enable=gte(t\,5)` is `overlay=enable=gte(t\,overlay_delay)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Slightly confused by the interval. Could you explain it with these parameters if possible? `input.mov` is 10 secs long. `overlay.mov` is 3 secs long. `output.mov` should be 10 secs long. `overlay.mov` should start at 7 seconds into `input.mov`

Comment: Overlay starts at 7, so `overlay=enable=gte(t\,7)`. Overlay.mov is shown from its beginning, so `setpts=PTS+7-0/TB` == `setpts=PTS+7/TB`

Comment: How about if i want to have also the audio kept in both videos? Because now when i try it, the audio from the overlay is gone. Thanks!

Comment: Insert `[0][1]amix[a]` into the filtergraph after the overlay and change `-map 0:a` to `-map [a]`

Comment: @Gyan can you please give an example of how to add this `[0][1]amix[a]` Is it supposed to be added in the same chain as overlay command?

Comment: I got it working but i had to remove `-c:a copy` since copy can't be used with filters, right?

Comment: @Gyan what should we change (in your command) if we want the overlay start at `0`, like what OP was doing? I did `gte(t\,0)` and `setpts=PTS+0/TB` but that didn't work.

Comment: @Gyan I have a very similar question and I have found a working solution, however it seems overly complex, if you have an idea (because you seems to be a ffmpeg guru!), it would be great :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66256414/mixing-various-audio-and-video-sources-into-a-single-video