# Overlay a video on another video at specific time with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay, video-processing

I am trying to overlay a video with another video. I followed the original command OP posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269387/ffmpeg-overlay-one-video-onto-another-video). And it works, but it overlays the video from time 0:

```
ffmpeg -i 720480.mp4 -i sdbug.mov -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]overlay[out]" -shortest -map [out] -map 0:1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 18  new.mp4
```

I tried the correct answer to specify a time, but it is not working for me: 1) the overlay starts at around second `12`, and 2) video is not played after the overlay is finished.

```
ffmpeg -i 720480.mp4 -i sdbug.mov -filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS+10/TB[a]; [0:v][a]overlay=enable=gte(t\,5):shortest=1[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy new.mp4
```

Anything changed recently on `FFmpeg`?! Why isn't it working?

Here is the output of this command (it finishes very fast):

```
ffmpeg version N-92906-g54109b1d14 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181201
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 25.100 / 56. 25.100
  libavcodec     58. 43.100 / 58. 43.100
  libavformat    58. 25.100 / 58. 25.100
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 46.101 /  7. 46.101
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '720480.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-07-26T09:23:16.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:50.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3181 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 2785 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-26T09:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      timecode        : 00:59:55:12
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 98 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-26T09:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 98 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-26T09:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 98 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-26T09:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:4: Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 98 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-26T09:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:5: Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-26T09:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : TimecodeMediaHandler
      timecode        : 00:59:55:12
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sdbug.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2018-08-29T14:50:13.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:10.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10504 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), bgra(progressive), 720x486, 9666 kb/s, SAR 109:120 DAR 109:81, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-08-29T14:50:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Animation
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
    Stream #1:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-08-29T14:50:13.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00;00
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (qtrle) -> setpts
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:4 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] using SAR=8/9
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] 264 - core 157 r2935 545de2f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'new.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.43.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 98 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-26T09:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 98 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-26T09:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 98 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-26T09:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:4: Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 98 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-07-26T09:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
frame=  599 fps= 92 q=-1.0 Lsize=   11556kB time=00:01:50.01 bitrate= 860.5kbits/s speed=16.8x
video:6173kB audio:5288kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.828358%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] frame I:8     Avg QP:13.24  size: 44134
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] frame P:174   Avg QP:18.62  size: 20916
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] frame B:417   Avg QP:21.31  size:  5583
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] consecutive B-frames:  6.0%  1.7%  5.5% 86.8%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] mb I  I16..4: 15.9% 58.9% 25.2%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] mb P  I16..4:  1.4% 13.6%  4.2%  P16..4: 36.6% 22.8% 12.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 9.0%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.9%  0.3%  B16..8: 46.4% 10.6%  2.9%  direct: 5.5%  skip:33.3%  L0:53.4% L1:36.9% BI: 9.7%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] 8x8 transform intra:68.5% inter:65.1%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 77.5% 89.5% 77.2% inter: 26.8% 48.1% 10.1%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] i16 v,h,dc,p: 50% 13% 13% 23%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 12% 17%  6%  8% 10%  7%  9%  7%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 13% 10%  7% 12% 11%  9%  9%  7%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 15% 24% 10%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] Weighted P-Frames: Y:5.2% UV:2.9%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] ref P L0: 60.1% 19.6% 15.8%  4.4%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] ref B L0: 91.6%  7.3%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] ref B L1: 97.2%  2.8%
[libx264 @ 000002b902a3f480] kb/s:2529.97
```

Comment: Now two problems: 1) no video is played after the overlay is finished (I see frame freezed!), and 2) It starts at around second 12!

Comment: Commands above are exact command. Updated with the output as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) to add a delay for [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i overlay.mov -filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[ovr];[0:v][ovr]overlay=enable=gte(t\,10):eof_action=pass,format=yuv420p[vid]" -map "[vid]" -map 0:a? -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Now if I want it to overlay at time `0`, which ones should I change?!

Comment: Don't forget to add the `/` after `t` in `gte(t,10)`

Comment: What difference does it make?! 5 vs 10

Comment: And you didn't say. Which values should I change to make it start from 0? I did `PTS+0` or `PTS` and no effect.

Comment: @TinaJ See the answer you linked to in your question.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But what should we change (in your command) if we want the overlay start at 0, like what my original command doing? I did `gte(t\,0)` and `setpts=PTS+0/TB` according to that answer, but that didn't work.

Comment: @TinaJ `-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=eof_action=pass,format=yuv420p[out]"`

Comment: umm this is a bit new different. Should I assume this answer is good maybe only for positive values (not `0`)?

Comment: @TinaJ You said you now wanted the overlay to start at duration 0. If you want that than you have no need for `setpts` and/or `enable`.

Comment: no need means "shouldn't" be there, right? Because changing the time to 0 doesn't work.

Comment: @TinaJ I guess I just don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So I'm trying to run this command in Python. Whatever time X is (can be 10, can be 0 also), I want to construct the command dynamically and replace X with my value `gte(t\,X)` and `setpts=PTS+X/TB` in code. Looks like if `X=0` this command doesn't work.

Comment: if still not understood, nevermind. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: @TinaJ Works for me.

Comment: works perfect for me, how to move overlay 20x20 pixels from left top corner

Comment: @david `overlay=x=10:y=10...` See [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) for more info.