# FFmpeg: Overlay one over another video including audio after a specific time

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Code has taken from following answer: [FFmpeg - Overlay one video onto another video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269387/ffmpeg-overlay-one-video-onto-another-video/35291260#35291260) and then little bit modified.

```
ffmpeg -i stream1.mp4 -i stream2.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS+5/TB[a]; \
                 [0:v][a]overlay=enable=gte(t\,5):shortest=1[out]; \
                 [0][1]amix[a]" \
-map [out] -map [a] \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-y output.mp4
```

stream1.mp4 duration, eg: 35 seconds and stream2.mp4 duration, eg: 30 seconds. I want to start overlay (stream2.mp4) video+audio after 5 seconds. Overlay (stream2.mp4) video starts as expected.

But overlay (stream2.mp4) audio starts from beginning. How do I start overlay (stream2.mp4) audio after 5 seconds also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [adelay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay):

```
ffmpeg -y -i stream1.mp4 -i stream2.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS+5/TB[v]; \
                 [0:v][v]overlay=enable=gte(t\,5):shortest=1,format=yuv420p[out]; \
                 [1:a]adelay=5s:all=1[a1];[0][a1]amix[a]" \
-map [out] -map [a] \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 \
output.mp4
```

If your `ffmpeg` is outdated you will have to use milliseconds and declare the delay for each channel, such as `adelay=5000|5000`.