# How do I use ffmpeg to overlay an effect for a certain amount of time?

Tags: ffmpeg

There is a command for FFMPEG that applies a filter to the video

```
ffmpeg -threads 2 -y -i 6.mp4 -vf rgbashift=rh=20:bh=-20 -hide_banner -y -vcodec mpeg4 -crf 23 -b:v 1000K -maxrate 1500K -bufsize 500K 7.mp4
```

The question is how to make it overlap a certain time
For example from 00:01:10 to 00:02:20
and then from 00:03:01 to 00:04:00?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269387/ffmpeg-overlay-one-video-onto-another-video) which may be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify time periods for ffmpeg effects to be applied by using the "enable" option.

In your case, the following command should do the trick:

```
ffmpeg -threads 2 -y -i 6.mp4 -vf rgbashift=rh=20:bh=-20:enable='between(t,70,140)+between(t,181,240)' -hide_banner -y -vcodec mpeg4 -crf 23 -b:v 1000K -maxrate 1500K -bufsize 500K 7.mp4
```

- 70 is 01:10 is seconds, same for the other timings
- The "+" between the 2 between clauses acts as an OR statement